# find max value of a key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
 [DoctorEducation] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24
                        [user_id] => 91
                        [degree_type_id] => 1
                        [college_hospital] => sms
                        [diploma_name] => 
                        [specialization_id] => 0
                        [start_date] => 02/2009
                        [end_date] => 03/2012
                        [year_passing] => 0000
                        [created] => 2015-10-09 13:14:23
                        [updated] => 2015-10-09 13:16:18
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 26
                        [user_id] => 91
                        [degree_type_id] => 5
                        [college_hospital] => sms
                        [diploma_name] => 
                        [specialization_id] => 48
                        [start_date] => 03/2012
                        [end_date] => 05/2014
                        [year_passing] => 0000
                        [created] => 2015-10-09 13:16:18
                        [updated] => 2015-10-09 13:16:18
                    )

            )
```

Now I want to find out which index i.e `0` or `1` or so on have the biggest value of `degree_type_id`. for example in current array index `1` has the biggest value of `degree_type_id` i.e 5.

I am getting this from DB. Here is the query

```
 $fields = array(
        'User.id',
        'User.first_name',
        'User.last_name',
        'User.gender',
        'User.dob',
        'User.image',
        'Specialization.name',
        'User.age'
    );
    $getSpecialist = $this->User->find('all', array('fields' => $fields), array('conditions' => array('User.role_id' => 3, 'User.status' => 1)));
```

Comment: If you're getting this from a database, why not use your database query to get it for you

Comment: @MarkBaker : yes , I am getting this from DB. Check my updated question for query.

Comment: `$maxId = array_search(array_column($myArray['DoctorEducation'], 'degree_type_id'), max(array_column($myArray['DoctorEducation'], 'degree_type_id')));`

Comment: are you using a framework, orm?

Comment: I am using framework `cakephp`.

Comment: make another query, and follow these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415386/cakephp-find-with-max

Comment: @monir009 : yes, I also don't know. I think I should investigate that.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    $max_index = null;
    $max_value = 0;
    foreach($DoctorEducation as $key => $array){
      if($array['degree_type_id'] > $max_value){
        $max_value = $array['degree_type_id'];
        $max_index = $key;
      }
    }
print_r($DoctorEducation[$max_index]);
```

This gives you the index and the value of the key with the highest *degree_type_id*

Comment: thanks. it worked. I didn't know how I miss that approach. I think feeling sleepy .. :D ;)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a faster way to do this, but here's my solution:

```
$to_compare = array(); 
foreach($DoctorEducation as $idx => $arr){
    $to_compare[$idx] = $arr['degree_type_id'];
}

$max = $to_compare[array_search(max($to_compare), $to_compare)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with several functions:

```
$key = array_search(max(array_column($array['DoctorEducation'], 'degree_type_id')),
                    $array['DoctorEducation']);
```

- Extract the appropriate column to an array
- Find the maximum value in that column array
- Search that column array for the maximum value, which returns the key

If there is more than one occurrence of the maximum value then you will get the first one.